# Is there anyway to execute the return statement of a method before await call in that method is completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async method in c# code, as shown in demo code--

```
public async Task<string> Method1()
{
    string s = "some text";
    await method2();
    return s;
}
```

Now the problem is - method2 take few minutes to complete but the UI update depends only on string s returned by Method1. 
This is hitting UI performance. Is there a way to return string s and do not wait for await call to complete.

Comment: If you don't want to wait until method2() finishes, then this function design is wrong. What are you trying to achieve with this code. May be a bigger picture will help better solve the problem.

Comment: If you dont want to wait then don't await. `await method2();` -> `method2();`

Comment: What should happen if `Method2` throws an exception?

Comment: If the returned string does not depend on calling `method2()` then split `Method1()` into two methods - one non-async one that returns the string, and an async one the awaits `method2()`, If the returned string *does* depend on `method2()` then you have no choice but to await it.

Comment: we can use ConfigureAwait(false) while calling method2() with await.
As a good practice, ConfigureAwait(false)  helps in increasing performance.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could just write

```
public string Method1()
{
    Method2();
    return "some text";
}
```

However, you'll get warnings.

You are doing a fire and forget on `Method2`, indicating that you don't care if `Method2` succeeds, fails, throws an exception or even completes before the host of your application shuts down.

I doubt very much this is what you actually want?

Comment: Also, if an unhandled exception happens in `Method2()` it can crash your whole app.

Comment: @GabrielLuci No it cannot, unless it is a `StackOverflowException` which would crash an app anyway. Every exception will be discarded since there is no `Task` object returned by `Method1`. `IAsyncStateMachine` will simply store exceptions in a defaulted `TaskAwaiter` that will later be discarded.

Comment: I just tested this. You're right, if `Method2()` returns a `Task`. If it's `async void`, then it will crash the application. Since the original code was awaiting `Method2()`, then it would return a `Task` and it would be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Task.Run() to call the async method without waiting for the reply.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var t = Task.Run(() => MyMethod());
        }

        static public async void MyMethod()
        {
            //some long running code
        }
```

This page details it more:

[Simplest way to do a fire and forget method in c# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613951/simplest-way-to-do-a-fire-and-forget-method-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Comment: There is no point in calling `Task.Run` if the method already executes asynchronous methods... You are trying to wrap IO based execution in a method intended for CPU based execution.

Comment: Fair enough - I thought that just calling it without awaiting would generate a warning but it seems it does not in VS2019.

Comment: @FCin: That's not true. It depends on what context this code is running in, which unfortunately we don't have visibility into. What you're saying is true for something like ASP.NET Core, but in a console app, WPF, WinForms, etc. the syncrhonization context will cause the async task to run on the UI thread by default. Using `Task.Run` ensures it goes to a different thread.

Comment: @ChrisPratt If e.g. WPF would schedule a method call on UI thread then it would block the UI thread, blocking windows message pump, which is not the usual case. Scheduler _might_ schedule a task on UI thread, but it doesn't have to. Depending on the implementation of `method2` it might schedule it on ThreadPool thread, create a timer/spinwait, create a windows pipe, return completed task, create a completely new thread, who knows what sits inside the method. Everything depends on whetever `method2` is asynchronously awaited internally creating AsyncTaskMethodBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your wrote in the specifications of Method1 that this function would do something that requires you to call Method2, otherwise you could write your procedure without calling Method2.

This means, that your caller expects some post condition. Alas you didn't write your post condition, so I have to write the following using fairly abstract terms.

Suppose Method2 has a post-condition Post2 (I'm leaving the pre-condition here out of the discussion)

Now what did you write as specification of Method1? I know you wrote a simplified version of your actual Method1, but it seems to be something like:

> Method2 will return a `Task<string>`, that, when awaited for, will have changed the state of the process into: Post2 AND the return value will be a string containing "some text".

If this is your specification, then you definitely should await for Method2.

An alternative specification could be:

> Method2 will return a `Task<string>`, that, when awaited for, **will have started Method2** AND the return value will be a string containing "some text".

If this is the case, you don't have to await for Method2. Your caller has no way to find out when Post2 is active, nor whether a problem occurred when trying to change the state of the machine to Post2.

It might be that at some point one of your callers want to be certain that Method2 has completed, and thus Post2 is met. Why don't you let the caller decide whether he wants to await for Method2?

Instead of returning `Task<string>`, you could return a Tuple containing the Task for Method2 and the returning string. See [Tuples in C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples)

```
public (string Text, Task Task> Method1()
{
    string s = "some text"; 
    Task method2Task = method2();

    return (Text: s, Task: method2Task);
}
```

Because you don't await, the method isn't async anymore.

Of course you can make do it in one statement:

```
return (Text: "Some text", Task: method2() );
```

Your caller should to something like:

```
var method1Result = method1();

// I'm not interested in Method2 right now, but I like to process the string result
ProcessText(method1Result.Text);

// if, after a while I want to be certain the Post2 is met, I'll have to await:
await method1Result.Task
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by removing await from `method2` invocation and using `Task.FromResult` on the string object which you are returning but it would be little inefficient :

```
public async Task<string> Method1()
{
    string s = "some text";
    method2();
    return await Task.FromResult(s);
}
```

Comment: That will just run synchronously, but with the overhead of `await` having to decide to run synchronously. See Jodrell's answer.

Comment: @GabrielLuci ofcourse that is the correct way, but what if we don't want to change the method signatures ? in that case this will be the way