# In c# is it mandatory to use async keyword for calling method when we use Task.Run() inside the method logic to run the thread in the background?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

Below is the code snippet:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetProduct(int id)
        {
            /* 
             ---- some main thread logic...
             */

            Task.Run(() => {
                /* 
             ---- some background thread logic...
             */
            });

            return View();
        }
```

In the above code can I call Task.Run() logic without the use of async keyword in the action method?
Is it mandatory to use async keyword with Task.Run()?

Please help me to get this clear.

Comment: Depends on whether you want it to `await` or not

Comment: A big difference (**though certainly not the only difference**) is by adding `await` your task will run `return View` **after** your task returns, whereas without this `await` `return View` will (likely) return **before** your task returns.

Comment: @Liam, thanks for the help... Actually I don't want to use await. the intention is to use Task.Run() is that I want to run two threads, the main thread should not wait for the logic of Task.Run(). Task.Run() logic should run in the background.

Comment: In which case, no, you don't want to use `await`. See [Simplest way to do a fire and forget method in c# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613951/simplest-way-to-do-a-fire-and-forget-method-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not mandatory.

You use the `async` keyword when you want to use `await` within a method.