# API async method call acting as eventHandler

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest, async-await

I have a scenario where I need to ensure the following :

1. UI, on button click makes a GET call to an API and waits for a response.
2. API method has to perform two tasks X and Y on the GET request, but it should return X's response as soon as it gets it and performs Y in the background.
3. UI is not aware if Y succeeds or not.

The challenge I am facing is returning a response back for X and at the same time triggering Y in parallel. Any safe thread pattern that can be followed here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to do a fire and forget method in c# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613951/simplest-way-to-do-a-fire-and-forget-method-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Comment: Tl;Dr `Task.Run(() => {})`