# Cannot wait process running until end

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadabortexception

I have one aspx code behind page, that uses a process (p) to call an application (exe file) as following the code:

```
p.Start();
while(!p.HasExited)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
p.Dispose();
```

The while loop to take waiting of 2s, but is always throwing the exception like below:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at Insyma.ContentUpdate.XmlReader.DoSleep()
```

At the statement `Thread.Sleep(2000)`.
So anybody can help me some solutions.
Thanks so much,

Comment: How long does the child process run for?

Comment: Did you force the parent process to end while it was in your `Thread.Sleep`? Why not use the built-in `WaitForExit` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AutoResetEvent

```
class BasicWaitHandle
{
   static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent (false);
   static void Main()
   {
       new Thread (Waiter).Start();        
       _waitHandle.WaitOne(); //wait for notification
       //Do operartion
   }

   static void Waiter()
   {
      //Do operations
      _waitHandle.Set(); //Unblock
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need some Fire and Forget pattern. thread is exiting because once page is been rendered its instance is prone to be disposed.. so this is may be what you need.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => FireAway());

private void FireAway()
{
p.Start();
while(!p.HasExited)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
p.Dispose();

}
```

For more info:
http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2009/05/14/fire-and-forget-class-for-asp-net.aspx

[Simplest way to do a fire and forget method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018610/simplest-way-to-do-a-fire-and-forget-method-in-c)

Regards.