# Parallel.For loop clean up

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am new to multi-threading.  I have a `Parallel.For` loop working great!

I do have a cancellation token.

Our DBA just happened to notice that I had a lot of active threads (I was testing and using the tool in a way it will not be used in production).

Anyway, I started looking for ways to clean up the threads after processing and cannot find anything.  Do I need to do clean up other than `cts.Cancel`?

Comment: (hint: when doing stuff where you mostly _wait_ for other systems, like database calls, best use async/await instead of threads.) can you please provide more context for your question? for example - the code? usually, threads aren't something you have to clean up after. probably you're forgetting some `using` statements for `Disposable` resources.  i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My development network is not connected to the internet so it is hard to copy code. 
 I am running the process in a dll called by a queuebackgroundworkitem.

It is very basic

var po = new ParallelOptions();
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

Parallel.For(o, page.Count, po, index =>
{
  CreateObject(page[index]);
});
cts.Cancel();

Comment: please actually _do read_ the articles i've linked to - and **edit** your question to provide additional information, while taking care of proper formatting. and make sure it contains _enough_ information. we can't spot problems in code you didn't provide.

Answer (score 1):

The `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach` methods have the nasty habit of [saturating the `ThreadPool`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261010/multiple-parallel-foreach-loops-in-net/66263583#66263583) when the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) option is not configured. This causes the `ThreadPool` to start injecting new threads in the pool, with a frequency of around one new thread per second. To keep the `ThreadPool` under control, just make sure that you have configured the parallel loop with a reasonable `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, like [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount):

```
var po = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };
```

Configuring the [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.cancellationtoken) option is only needed if you want to cancel the loop while it's running. Using it for cleaning-up purposes is unlikely to have any effect.