# Async or parallel function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I am working on an application (ASP.NET MVC5) which saves a pile of data to the database in one go. The method which saves the data takes time to do it and I do not want to block user interface.

Here I have created a test program which will sleep for 10 sec and I do not want to return any result from this program.

```
public Task SaveFunc()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    return null;
}
public void ShowFunction()
{
SaveFunc();
retrun "Your request is under process";
}
```

Now, how do I call SaveFunc in such a way that I do not have to wait for the result.

Comment: You can use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace: `TaskFactory.StartNew(() => /* my async action */);` Be aware: in mvc, it will be block request anyway (request will wait for end of task). If you use mvc, you need to check async controllers.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1018610/2974754).

Comment: *how do I call SaveFunc in such a way that I do not have to wait for the result.* What do you mean by that? do you want the query to execute in a *fire and forget* style?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes i want exactly the same

Comment: Read [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer asumes you are using `ASP.NET MVC` - if this is not the case please update your question:*

Since .NET 4.5.2 you can [do the following](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2):

```
public ActionResult ShowFunction()
{
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(cancellationToken =>
    {
        // Some long-running job
    });
    return Content("Your request is under process");
}
```

If you are still on an old .NET version you can do something like:

```
public ActionResult ShowFunction()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c =>
    {
        // Some long-running job
    });
    return Content("Your request is under process");
}
```

but the execution of [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(v=vs.110).aspx) can be canceled by an AppDomain-recycle so you need to take care of such scenarios. Since .NET 4.0 you can also use [`Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /*...*/ });`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx) and get a `Task` to work with.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Because the OP asked `Async or parallel function **in mvc**`? With `MVC` I asumed ASP.NET MVC...

Comment: @PatrickHofman; Me too, but I hesitated to edit it, as it *could be* that the OP actually implemented MVC for another technology like WPF - lets see how the OP responds...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the async method `Task.Delay` since `Thead.Sleep` is synchronous and blocks the current context. You also need to return a `Task` from the method instead of `null` and await the `Task` to wait until it ends. In the mean time, your program can run as is:

```
public Task SaveFunc()
{
    return Task.Delay(10000);
}

public async void ShowFunction()
{
    await SaveFunc().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: please explain your code if possible how it will work

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Added. Is this sufficient to you?

Comment: Here you still have to wait for the result, you just don't block the thread. The OP asked `call SaveFunc in such a way that I do not have to wait for the result`...

Comment: @ChrFin: The result is awaited, but the current requested keeps processing and returning. The `ConfigureAwait(false)` decouples it from the current context.

Comment: is it necessary to call ConfigureAwait?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: `ConfigureAwait` is not necessary per se, but without it you could cause deadlocks. You should always use it excpet when context matters...