# how to properly call callback on dispatcher.begininvoke?

Tags: c#, dispatcher

I assume that I can just call

```
var dispatcherOp = Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Action());
dispatcherOp.Completed += dispatcherOp_Completed;
```

but then I am a little concerned. If begininvoke is asynchronous, then What prevents the dispatcher from completing the action before I get the returned dispatcher operation and attach to the completed event.

i assume that this must be impossible, but if so, I would like to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: nothing.

There are three possible approaches:

1.) You can decide that it is not important to wait for the operation to be executed. If so, then you are choosing the [fire and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018610/simplest-way-to-do-a-fire-and-forget-method-in-c) strategy.

2.) You can decide that you want a synchronous request, so you await, like SLaks suggested.

3.) You can keep the request to be asynchronous, but use a [callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You are correct; this is not safe.  You should simply `await` the operation.

Comment: not sure i understand what you mean. could you give me an example of how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Dispatcher does not have a callback function it takes for begininvoke.

Synchronous operation is not desired in my program, but I realized after a google search or two that I can lock on it like this

```
lock (this)
            {
                var dispatcherOp = Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(MyAction, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
                dispatcherOp.Completed += dispatcherOp_Completed;
            }



void dispatcherOp_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lock (this)
            {

            }

        }
```

and then lock again on the same object in the completed function so that the dispatcher can't complete till you have finished attaching your handler.

Answer (score 0):

There is never a reason to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` in a modern application.

If your code models a background operation, then use `async`/`await`, with `IProgress<T>` for any progress updates.

If your code models an asynchronous sequence, then use Rx (Reactive Extensions) with `ObserveOn` to update objects with UI thread affinity.

Comment: is there a way to use async await to call stuff on the GUI thread?

Comment: I've always found that it's better to reverse that logic: the GUI thread drives everything in the app. Nothing ever calls the GUI thread. Background ops can report results (which the GUI thread retrieves with `await`), updates (`IProgress<T>`), or events (Rx), but they never actually call the GUI thread directly.

Comment: ok read some examples and i think i understand it better. reading about reactive extensions now. never heard of it before