# Fire and forget method in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Fire and forget method in C#**

I refered different issues for 'Fire and Forget in C#'

i.e.
[Simplest way to do a fire and forget method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018610/simplest-way-to-do-a-fire-and-forget-method-in-c)
.
.
and few several,

but i have an another issue with the same.i wrote following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //fireAway(i);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fireAway(i));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Main Finished");
        Console.Read();
    }

public static void fireAway(int i)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("FireAway" + i);
    }
```

where i am **expecting output** like

Main Finished

FireAway0

FireAway1

FireAway2

FireAway3

FireAway4

**but output is**

Main Finished

FireAway5

FireAway5

FireAway5

FireAway5

FireAway5

very honestly i am new to threading concept, i need help. How can i meet with expected output..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Comment: fireaway method closes over (i) variable, and since you're waiting in that method for 5 seconds, (i) will become 5 before you write it's value

Answer (score 1):

The threads are started after the loop is finished. When the loop is finished the value of i is 5. You have to capture the value of i before you send it to StartNew(..)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
      int tmp = i;
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fireAway(tmp));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should pass parameter to your method, not use i, because the method will start to execute only after you finish to iterate, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456(v=vs.110).aspx)