# How to cancel BackgroundJob or let a newjob don't retry?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

my case similar the example, a user presses a 'report' button to start a long-running reporting job. You add this job to the queue and send the report's result to your user via email when it's completed. But, I don't need retries job execution when the job failed. I want job stop and send notification. And can cancel on service.

```cs
        public void CancelAllMyJob()
        {
            var jobs = backgroundJobStore.GetWaitingJobsAsync(int.MaxValue).Result.Where(o => o.JobType.Contains(nameof(MyJob))).ToList();
            if (jobs.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (BackgroundJobInfo job in jobs)
                {
                    backgroundJobStore.DeleteAsync(job).Wait();
                }
            }
        }
```

```cs
        public async Task StartMyJob(MyJobInput input)
        {
            MyJobArgs args = new MyJobArgs
            {
                TenantId = AbpSession.TenantId,
                UserId = AbpSession.UserId.Value,
            };
            var id = await backgroundJobManager.EnqueueAsync<MyJob, MyJobArgs >(args);
            (await backgroundJobStore.GetAsync(Convert.ToInt64(id))).TryCount = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Are your codes satisfying the issue?! If you are trying to do a task only once, you'd better call it once in another thread. I assume the issue will be solved by [fire and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018630/7855321) pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
    public async Task StartMyJob(MyJobInput input)
            {
                MyJobArgs args = new MyJobArgs
                {
                    TenantId = AbpSession.TenantId,
                    UserId = AbpSession.UserId.Value,
                };
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
                    {
                        myJob.Execute(args);
                    }
                });
    }
```

It's work, thanks!