# How to invoke a delegate call as Fire-And-Forget

Tags: c#, events, delegates, fire-and-forget

I have a .NET Standard library that is able to report back its progress. I would like the program **not** to block until the progress reporting method has completed. Instead I would like a Fire-And-Forget pattern where the work can continue inside `DoWork()`

```
class Foo
{
   public delegate void ProgressEvent(double progress, double max);
   public ProgressEvent ReportProgress { get; set; }

   public void DoSomeWork()
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++)
      {
         // Do work
         ReportProgress?.Invoke(i, 1000);   // I do not want to wait for the method to return here
      }
   }
}
```

So far, I have put it as a requirement that the method body assigned to ReportProgress must execute quickly. But if there is a good coding solution, I would not like to rely on requirements.

There is the possibility to wrap the invocation of ReportProgress in a new thread, but that seems inefficient - that will spawn 1000 threads.

This question suggests that I should somehow expose a ThreadPool in my class, but I am not sure that this makes sense:
[Simplest way to do a fire and forget method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018610/simplest-way-to-do-a-fire-and-forget-method-in-c)

*How would you approach this situation?*

**EDIT:**
I belive that the user of the class is using it like this. Note that there is a potential slow update of a remote database. This customer was the reason I needed to rethink the struture.

```
void HandleRequest(int requestID)
{
    
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(()=>
    {
        double currentProgress = 0;
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.ReportProgress = (progress, max) =>
        {
            double newProgress = progress/max;
            if(newProgress > currentProgress)
            {
                currentProgress = newProgress;
                UpdateRemoteDataBase(currentProgress, requestID);
            }
        }
        t.DoWork();
    });
}
```

Comment: Try the key word ```async``` ```await```

Comment: @folmerbrem Have you considered to use `IProgress<T>` ([1](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html))?

Comment: @MichaelMao Yes I was looking into the async pattern as it really seems like the way to go. But I have a hard time putting it into my context when using delegates. An example would really be helpful if you can spare a few moments.

Comment: Could you provide an example how will you use this class

Comment: @MichaelMao I added a code that likely represents how the customer is using the library

Comment: If your user use a new thread to run this then I think it will not get block?

Comment: Yes but I cannot control what my user is doing. I can only point to recommendations, but I would like to code my way out of this instead by firing the Invoke and getting on with DoWork.

Comment: What is you ```t.DoWork()``` mean? ```Foo.DoSomeWork() ```?

Answer (score 0):

How about just wrap your `DoSomework` with `Thread`

```
 class Foo
    {
        public delegate void ProgressEvent(double progress, double max);
        public ProgressEvent ReportProgress { get; set; }

        public void DoSomeWork()
        {
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    // Do work
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    ReportProgress?.Invoke(i, 1000);   // I do not want to wait for the method to return here
                }
            });
            workerThread.Start();
            return;
        }
    }
```