# asp.net Long running Tasks and Checking it's Status

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay i have asp.net webproject. Somewhere in this project, the user should be able to activate a function.

This function does a lot of work and need some time (like 5min). In this time it should be possible to call other functions of this class. Like checking a variable or whatever.

if possible: i don't want to add javascript in any form. Should work completely through code behind.

Any Ideas of how this can work?

Comment: Long running jobs should be done by external services that are kicked off by the ASP page, and then queried periodically for completion. I'd hate to watch a web page load for 5 minutes (which will probably time out anyway). Look at things like [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading and Asynchronous Programming?

Please refer to the following links for more info:

[Multi-Threading in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET)

[Running an asynchronous operation triggered by an ASP.NET web page request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672237/running-an-asynchronous-operation-triggered-by-an-asp-net-web-page-request)

[ASP.NET - Multi Threading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_multi_threading.htm)

[Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx)